# Cant call .all on dataset

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sequel-gem

I am running into problems when changing a query from plain sql (note: I am not using AR but sequel)

So this works:

```
Post.fetch(
    "SELECT
      COUNT(*) as count, HOUR(created_at) as date, class_type
    FROM
      tours t
    WHERE
      t.created_at Between ? and ?
    GROUP BY hour(t.created_at), flavor", @range_begins, @range_ends
    ).all
```

And it returns the expected array. But this doesnt:

```
Post.select("COUNT(*) as count, HOUR(created_at) as date, class_type")
    .where(created_at: @basic_range)
    .group_by("HOUR(created_at), flavor")
    .all
```

But in the console (without the .all at the end) the query generated from that looks good (formatted for better reading):

```
<Sequel::Mysql2::Dataset:
"SELECT
  'COUNT(*) as count, HOUR(created_at) as date, class_type'
FROM
  `posts`
WHERE
  ((`created_at` >= '2014-05-01 00:00:00') AND (`created_at` <= '2014-05-01 23:59:59')) 
GROUP BY
  'HOUR(created_at), flavor'">
```

Adding the ".all" at the end returns an array looking like this:

```
[#<Tour @values={:"COUNT(*) as count, HOUR(created_at) as date, class_type"=>"COUNT(*) as count, HOUR(created_at) as date, class_type"}>]
```

what am I missing?
Thanks in advance for the help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you are writing query with `where` function, you dont need to write `.all` in the end, it will by default give all the results matching the query parameters. You just need to do :

```
Post.select("COUNT(*) as count, HOUR(created_at) as date, class_type")
    .where(created_at: @basic_range)
    .group_by("HOUR(created_at), flavor")
```

Comment: I thought you precisely should have attributes from `group_by` and `having` in `select` to work.

Comment: @zishe: It's implementation dependent. For example, Oracle requires that the columns named in the 'group by' clause appear in the select statement. Others, including MySql, for example, do not.

Comment: Hey Saurabh, I tried it without the .all and it doesnt return an array with the data, just the dataset:
<Sequel::Mysql2::Dataset:
"SELECT
  'COUNT(*) as count, HOUR(created_at) as date, class_type'
FROM
  `posts`
WHERE
  ((`created_at` >= '2014-05-01 00:00:00') AND (`created_at` <= '2014-05-01 23:59:59')) 
GROUP BY
  'HOUR(created_at), flavor'">